# How Can I Refactor To Avoid Duplication?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
$('#foo').validate({
  errorPlacement: (e, el) => {
    /**
     * /* Insert .error after offending <input>'s <label>.
     */
    e.insertAfter(el.next('.form__label')).animate({
      opacity: 1,
      top: '-=10px',
    }, 'fast');
  },
  messages: {
    tc: 'Please accept our Terms & Conditions!',
  },
});

$('#bar').validate({
  errorPlacement: (e, el) => {
    /**
     * /* Insert .error after offending <input>'s <label>.
     */
    e.insertAfter(el.next('.form__label')).animate({
      opacity: 1,
      top: '-=10px',
    }, 'fast');
  },
});
```

I'm working with jqueryvalidation.org with two different `<form>` containers on my page. This is working ok as is, but, I'm sure that there's a better way to extrapolate that `errorPlacement` Object, right? I'm just not seeing it right now...

I tried something like this:

```
/**
 * Customize placement of created error labels.
 * (https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)
 * @param {$} e created error label
 * @param {$} el invalid element
 */
function ep(e, el) {
 // Insert .error after offending <input>'s <label>.
   e.insertAfter(el.next('.form__label')).animate({
      opacity: 1,
      top: '-=10px',
    }, 'fast');
}

$('#foo').validate({
  errorPlacement: function ep(e, el) {
  // Insert .error after offending <input>'s <label>.
  e.insertAfter(el.next('.form__label')).animate({
      opacity: 1,
      top: '-=10px',
    }, 'fast');
   },
  messages: {
    tc: 'Please accept our Terms & Conditions!',
  },
});

$('#bar').validate({
  errorPlacement: ep(e, el), // This throws error of 'unknown' e
});
```

Comment: I imagine the validation will be different for each, like the messages and stuff? Because if not you could just use `$('#foo, #bar').validate({})`

Comment: No @MattFletcher, the `.validate()` method absolutely does not work like that.  If you attach it to a jQuery selector that matches more than one `form`, only the first form will be used and the rest will be ignored.  [Refer to the docs please](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-validating-multiple-forms-on-one-page).  Even so, the OP is showing that he also has some unique options within each form, as you initially mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need, because there something called [`.setDefaults()`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/) that is already part of this plugin.  Anything you put inside will become the default for all instances of `.validate()` on the page.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ // <- will be used on all instances of .validate() on this page
    errorPlacement: function(e, el) {
        e.insertAfter(el.next('.form__label')).animate({
            opacity: 1,
            top: '-=10px',
        }, 'fast');
    }
});

$('#foo').validate({
    messages: {
        tc: 'Please accept our Terms & Conditions!',
    }
});

$('#bar').validate({
    // other options
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the function that **is to be called** as a function that **has been called**.

When you do `errorPlacement: ep(e, el)`, the function part of `ep(e, el)` is called when you set up the object, not when errorPlacement is triggered. You just need to pass the function name itself without the parens.

```
$('#bar').validate({
  errorPlacement: ep,
});
```

The question of how to best refactor is probably too opinion-based to really answer, though. But what you're doing with splitting the function out seems correct.

Comment: Also is `top: '-=10px'` correct? Never seen that syntax before and looks kinda wrong, but I may be the wrong'n.

Comment: I'd probably go for sparky's option as he seems to be the grandmaster of jquery-validate. But hopefully my answer still helps somewhat with why you encountered your error.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ They use that syntax in example when changing top position. I have yet to get back to this, as I may be making some changes to the HTML of the whole thing.